# PayPal 2 forms?

Tags: php, paypal

I currently have a checkout page where users fill in their information, when they submit, their information is stored and it prints out a PayPal button so they can pay.

.

The question is, how can I redirect them automaticly as if they have clicked the PayPal button as soon as the information is stored?

Comment: submit to your server, process, submit to pay pal using curl

Comment: there is no "curl form"

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Javascript to check the values and place them in a hidden element that correlates with paypal POST values.

Comment: Honestly? 2 forms is the best way to go. It provides the user a way to look at the data they have passed to you and edit it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in a solution, I have found it.

Add an ID to your form

```
<form id="paypal">
```

Add this jQuery to your website

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#paypal').submit();
});
```

This will it submit the form on page load.